# Connectiong to VSTS in Mobile Center (Error getting list of repositories: TypeMismatchError)

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, mobile-center

I create new application in Mobile Center and I want to connect to source repository. My repository is on Visual Studio Team Services. When select repository, i get next message:

**Error getting list of repositories: TypeMismatchError**

Can anybody help me with this error.

Comment: Do you mean select Visual Studio Team Services service in Build section of Mobile Center? I cannot reproduce this issue. What’s the result if you connect to other service?

Comment: Can you please contact Mobile Center support by using the blue chat button at the bottom right? Thanks!